# Android/Gradle: App name based on build type *and* product flavor

Tags: android, gradle

I have 3 build types (debug, UAT and release) and 2 flavors (international and local).

I have my app name defined in a xml file named "product_name.xml":

```
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:ignore="MissingTranslation">

   <string name="app_title">Awesome App</string>

</resources>
```

I want to change the app name based on the build variant (build type + flavor). E.g:

- For variant InternationalDebug -> Awesome App (intl) debug
- For variant InternationalUAT   -> Awesome App (intl) UAT
- For variant LocalUAT           -> Awesome App (local) UAT

and so on.

How would I do about this? All the examples I've seen show me how to change the name based on *either* build type or the flavor but **not** both.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could create src-folders for your variants and place your custom strings there:

```
src
|-> InternationalDebug
|   |->res/values/strings.xml <-- place your app_title here
|-> LocalUAT
|   |->res/values/strings.xml <-- place your app_title here
|-> main (contains your main source code.
```